# Pass reference type across a DB Link

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Am trying to pass a reference type over a DB link, but am getting an error telling me its an illegal reference to the DB link in the procedure. I have specified it in the body and spec of the package and am not sure how to resolve it after searching for a solution. Am using oracle 10g for that reference type to an 11g oracle DB.

**Version:**
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0

```
[Error] PLS-00331 (13: 43): PLS-00331: illegal reference to test.DATA_T@TESTDB('PARAMETERS')
```

And it seems to be an issue here in the spec of the package:

```
   PROCEDURE SendCollection(o_data IN OUT data_t@TESTDB,
                   o_seq  IN OUT seq_t@TESTDB,
                   i_flag IN     CHAR);
```

I thought the above was correct, any pointers and advice would be welcome

Comment: Last I looked, I don't believe this is possible.  If it is possible, it's very likely to be highly version-dependent so you really want to specify the precise version(s) of Oracle you're using.

Comment: I also don't think it's possible, because your local instance would have no way of knowing if the remote type was modified or dropped; which it needs to be able to invalidate your procedure and then recompile it when used. [It isn't specifically listed as a restriction though](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/ds_concepts002.htm#i1108232).

Comment: Added as recommended, oracle versions: oracle (10g) is where am  passing  the reference type and oracle (11g) is where am passing it too

Comment: Are you 100% Sure it isn't possible? It is strange that its not listed there too

Comment: No, not 100%, but I didn't think it could be done, and the error suggests it isn't allowed. But the error doesn't seem to be pointing to the declaration; what is the code that's passing `'PARAMETERS'`, and how is the type defined on the remote DB? Maybe a small test case would help.

Comment: The parameters are just (o_data,o_seq,'T')two collection types and a char, it just seems that its illegal to pass type via the spec but it knows the links there, am not sure at all..

Comment: [The 11.1 docs on datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/constant.htm#LNPLS01310) do not mention a DB link in their definition of "datatype" which, coupled with the errors you've seen and the comments by JustinCave and AlexPoole, lead me to believe that a procedure parameter cannot reference a type defined in a remote database. If you can make it work let us know. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References to remote types are not allowed.  The documentation implies this is not possible but is not 100% clear on the point.

(Using community wiki since this answer is a summary of the comments.)

**Update: Remote Database Object References (works)**

Oracle is terrible with some of their documentation.  Sometimes one has to try it to really be sure.  A Working Solution:

```
DECLARE

   v_rec_sample sample_table@remotedb%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

   select *
     into v_rec_sample
     from doj_crime@remotedb
    where rownum = 1;

   dbms_output.put_line(v_rec_sample.crime_detail);
   dbms_output.put_line(v_rec_sample.location);

END;
```

It works.  One can use a dblink and a remotely defined object to create data type definitions on locally declared variables and collections.

Answer (score 3):

The thread is still open so I will answer for whoever might need help later on.
If you want to pass an **object**, then that is forbidden by Oracle according to [Oracle docs: Restriction on Using User-Defined Types with a Remote Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#CIHBIBEA):

> Objects or user-defined types (specifically, types declared with a SQL CREATE TYPE statement, as opposed to types declared within a PL/SQL package) are currently useful only within a single database.

However, you can send **record** or **table** types via DB link, but you will have to:

1. Either assign them an OID and create them with the **same** OID on both databases:

   ```
   -- Obtain an OID
   SELECT SYS_OP_GUID() FROM DUAL;

   -- Result
   SYS_OP_GUID()
   ----------------
   D38A360CF86C41618DC2C40B551214C3

   -- Create your type
   create or replace type MY_TAB oid 'E8892B5D76E7419A951AEBA63A7AB3BF' as table of varchar2(50);
   ```
2. Or put them in a package on the remote database:

   ```
   -- Create a DB link API package
   create or replace package DBLINK_API as
     type MY_TAB is table of varchar2(50);
   end DBLINK_API;

   -- And a function that uses that type
   create or replace function getCount(myPar DBLINK_API.MY_TAB) return number is
   begin
     return myPar.count;
   end getCount;
   ```

---

After that you can use it from your database. First let's create some test table with data.

```
create table TEST_TABLE
(
  ID varchar2(50) not null
);

insert into TEST_TABLE values('Value 1');
insert into TEST_TABLE values('Value 2');
insert into TEST_TABLE values('Value 3');
insert into TEST_TABLE values('Value 4');
insert into TEST_TABLE values('Value 5');
```

And then finally use the local table to send a table of IDs to the remote function, that is very useful for counting for us:

```
declare
  vals DBLINK_API.MY_TAB@MY_DBLINK;
begin
  select ID bulk collect
  into   vals
  from   TEST_TABLE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(getCount@MY_DBLINK(vals));
end;
```

It looks like an overkill in this example and you may prefer to do the select from the TEST_TABLE in the remote procedure using a DB link to your database instead. I am not sure how would performance be affected, perhaps this approach would be better for larger tables or slow selects, but it would have the same result.